# Wami audio recorder, callback functions not called

Tags: javascript, flash, audio

I am using Wami Recorder

https://code.google.com/p/wami-recorder/

The problem is that the callback function don't execute when the playing of audio get finished.

Here is the code that I am using :

```
function startPlaying()
{
    Wami.startPlaying(playBackUrl, startfn, finishedfn, failedfn );
}

function startfn()
{
  alert('start');
}
function finishedfn()
{
  alert('finish');
}
function failedfn ()
{
  alert('failed');
}
```

Initially I am calling the `startPlaying()`, which starts to play the audio file.
Even when the audio get over the `finishedfn` does not get called. Is there a bug in Wami Recorder ?

I have even tried by changing the definition of function like.

```
var finishedfn = function ()
{
  alert('finish');
}
```

But this has not helped me either.
There is hardly any help available for Wami on Google/Stackoverflow. :(

Answer (score 2):

Wami includes the helper function **Wami.nameCallback** to allow you to pass callbacks. As Garland noted, the flash object actually takes strings. You can use the nameCallback function to convert your callbacks into strings. If you look at the included gui.js file you'll see this in action.

Here's sample usage:

```
Wami.startRecording('/myUrl', Wami.nameCallback(function () {
  alert('started recording');    
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a pretty late response, but I just came across the same problem and thought I should share, on the off chance you still need to know, and hopefully to save anyone else a bit of time.

The JS function Wami.startPlaying() calls the same function inside the Flash WAMI object, which takes the following parameters:

```
url:String,
startedCallback:String = null,
finishedCallback:String = null,
failedCallback:String = null
```

As you can see the 3 callback functions actually take strings (not raw functions), so to successfully get the callback you need to pass call

```
Wami.startPlaying(playBackUrl, "startfn()", "finishedfn()", "failedfn()");
```

Comment: I used some other Sound Recorder for my purpose. I am not working on this now, but as far as I remember I tried this thing before; As is expected this was actually calling the functions startfn, finishedfn and failedfn just at the time the line `Wami.startPlaying(playBackUrl, "startfn()", "finishedfn()", "failedfn()");` is written. Anyways, I will try it out some time later. Thanks.